# PostgreSQL: How to pull relevant data for each row identified by a contained value

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have a database full of Chemical Data. In a table, each row of course contains a set of columns. One of these is what I want; the ID. One of these is what I am trying to identify the row by; cas_number.

I want to make a query or script that can take a list eg; (77-58-7, 77-58-7, 12578-12-0,...) and return the respective ID for each cas_number in the list.

So far I have tried to use the basic WHERE IN (_) query, only to get errors. After Googling around for a while I found nothing else probably due to the weird wording of my question. Hopefully typed out it makes more sense.

Edit to add sample data in CSV format.

```
id,cas_number
515,77-58-7
123,77-99-6
12,101-02-0
564,126-58-9
321,2452-01-9
624,12065-90-6
643,12202-17-4
15,12578-12-0
62,15535-79-2
77,15546-11-9
536,15571-58-1
55,15647-08-2
33,25448-25-3
22,25550-98-5
326,26544-23-0
123,27107-89-7
321,32509-66-3
234,35674-68-1
543,57583-34-3
456,57583-35-4
765,62229-08-7
53,68109-88-6
31,77745-66-5
86,91031-62-8
```

Comment: What was the query?  What was the error?  `IN` needs a column name (or something other than `WHERE`) immediately to the left of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First make a table from your list using `unnest` and then join.

```sql
select id, cas_number 
  from _table 
 inner join unnest(string_to_array('4141-41-53, 535-35-135, 5136-662-32', ', ')) v 
    on cas_number = v;
```

or as a parameterized query -

```sql
select id, cas_number 
  from _table 
 inner join unnest(string_to_array(:cas_list, ', ')) v on cas_number = v;
```

Ordering the result :

```sql
select id, cas_number 
  from _table 
 inner join unnest(string_to_array(:cas_list, ', ')) with ordinality t(v, o)
    on cas_number = t.v
 order by t.o;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried both of these solutions but they each return 2 empty columns "id" and "cas_number".

Comment: Pls. provide sample data

Comment: Yessir, will edit my original post to provide.

Comment: Does the data provided work to import to a table as CSV file? I was not sure how to get StackOverflow tables to work.

Comment: It's fine, will do.

Comment: The values in the list are not present in the sample data so the result is empty. Try `'15647-08-2, 25448-25-3, 25550-98-5, 26544-23-0'`

Comment: Right, the short hand list I originally wrote was random data for example purposes. The data I was querying was with data that was certainly in the table. 

What I would be trying to do with the CSV data is to create a table, then input only the "cas_number" data, to retrieve all respective ID's. Did I word this in a way that makes sense?

Comment: Found the problem! I just need to add spaces after the commas and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes you did so. Then pls. accept the answer.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm One more thing, if you are still available. Any way to have the results returned in the order I typed them in?